# Custom Pair Potential in HOOMD

Tags: python, simulation

I am learning to perform MD simulations in Python using HOOMD 4.0.0. I want to implement a simple parabolic pair potential, something of the form

```
U = epsilon * (r - sigma)^2
```

I don't see anything of a similar form in the list of pair potentials that HOOMD offers, so I guess I need to make it myself. I came across this code snippet:

```
class MyCustomForce(hoomd.force.Custom):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCustomForce).__init__(aniso=True)
        
    def set_forces(self, timestep):
        with self.cpu_local_force_arrays as arrays:
            ...
```

I presume that I will need to complete this class, but it is unclear to me how I would proceed.

Which features should I add to this class, and does anyone have a working example?

Thanks!